# ORACLE REPORTS - Frame printed in the middle of another frame, does not respect the order on the layout editor

Tags: oracle, report, frame, oraclereports

My problem is that I have a frame that should be showed on the end of my report.. But when it's printed, the frame goes to the middle of it, right in the center of another block.

For example, on the layout editor:

```
m_1
m_2
m_3
m_4
m_5
```

when I print:

```
m_1
m_2
m_5  ← Note the difference
m_3
m_4
```

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in a previous question you asked, you'll have to fix it within the layout editor.

- pay attention to frames' positions,
- what belongs to what

  - if necessary, move them *forward* or *backward*; sometimes several steps are required
  - it is easier to spot what goes where if you paint frames into different colors. Once everything is OK, remove colors
- maybe you'll have to **anchor** one frame to another